# Can't copy built project .dll file into the Docker container

Tags: docker, dll, dockerfile

I can't copy my built project .dll file into the container.

It's present in the bin/Debug folder, but not in the Solution. Maybe that's the problem?.. Anyway, tried ADD, RUN cp, absolute path, relative path, forward slash, and backward slash, but nothing helped. Docker can't find the .dll he needs to copy.

Please, help.

Comment: What is the directory structure and what error are you getting?

Comment: Updated the ticket.
Error is:
 => ERROR [14/14] COPY   /VaftExamples/bin/Debug/VaftExamples.dll     /VaftExamples.dll                                                                                 0.0s
------
 > [14/14] COPY   /VaftExamples/bin/Debug/VaftExamples.dll     /VaftExamples.dll:
------
failed to compute cache key: "/VaftExamples/bin/Debug/VaftExamples.dll" not found: not found

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I needed to add a dot before /bin/

```
COPY ["./bin/Debug/VaftExamples.dll", "/VaftExamples.dll"]
```